# How to theme Foundation 6 hollow button with sass

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation-6

I try to theme my own hollow button with sass for my Foundation 6 theme:

```
.light-hollow-button{
    @include button-hollow;
}
```

But how do I have to style the link color, border-color and border-color on hover?

Answer (score 1):

```
.light-hollow-button{
    @include button-hollow;
    &:hover{
        color: // your color;
        border-color: // your color;
    }
}
```

Try with this!